# Copy subfolders and files in msbuild

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-4.0

I'm unable to copy subfolders and files with this code:

```
<ItemGroup>
<Compile Include="C:\Test\Folder1\text.txt"/>
<Compile Include="C:\Test\text1.txt"/>
</ItemGroup>
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(Compile)" DestinationFiles="@(Compile->'C:\Destination\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')" />
```

I get this error: Could not find a part of the path.

How to copy C:\Test\ files and subfolders to C:\Destination\ with msbuild ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I pasted your code inside a target, created the needed files locally, and I was able to successfully copy those files by running your snippet in MSBuild. Do the source files exist? Maybe try running MSBuild with diagnostic logging enabled, to see if you can get more error details.

Comment: Destination folder files : C:\Destination\text.txt and C:\Destination\text1.txt, but I need subfolders C:\Destination\Folder1\text.txt and C:\Destination\text1.txt. It only copies files, but not subfolders which is my problem.

Comment: I see. My primary goal was to address the error you received, which I didn't experience when running your code. See my submitted answer for details regarding the RecursiveDir inclusion in the destination paths.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for the [RecursiveDir metadata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164313.aspx) to be populated, you must specify a recursive wildcard (double asterisks) in your items' paths. The `**` wildcard will mark the relative point at which the RecursiveDir should be applied. In your example, it sounds like you'd want to add the `**` wildcard after `C:\Test`, so your code would need to look like the following example:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="C:\Test\**\Folder1\text.txt"/>
    <Compile Include="C:\Test\**\text1.txt"/>
</ItemGroup>
<Copy SourceFiles="@(Compile)" DestinationFiles="@(Compile->'C:\Destination\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')" />
```

Adding the wildcard as shown above will copy the files to the following locations:

```
C:\Destination\text1.txt
C:\Destination\Folder1\text.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

The same as in response above, but without additional list transformation:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="C:\Test\**\Folder1\text.txt"/>
    <Compile Include="C:\Test\**\text1.txt"/>
</ItemGroup>
<Copy SourceFiles="@(Compile)" DestinationFolder="C:\Destination\%(RecursiveDir)" />
```